# When adding iPhone nib file SIGBRT error occurs

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have developed a Web Browser app called iBrowse for iPad. Now when I try to add iPhone support with a xib file I get a SIGBRT error in the Simulator.

The app uses xib files as the main page and I have had the iPad xib file since I created the app and it works fine. Because I want iPhone support I added a new iPhone xib file (with .h and .m files). When I make the Application Type Universal and select the xib file from the dropdown I get the following error when I launch the app for iPhone.

`2014-01-07 14:03:35.262 iBrowse[2207:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x753e440> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c95012 0x10d2e7e 0x1d1dfb1 0xb7ee41 0xb005f8 0xb000e7 0xb2ab58 0x234019 0x10e6663 0x1c9045a 0x232b1c 0x2348da 0x1668b 0x169a2 0x15876 0x26cb5 0x27beb 0x19698 0x1bf0df9 0x1bf0ad0 0x1c0abf5 0x1c0a962 0x1c3bbb6 0x1c3af44 0x1c3ae1b 0x1517a 0x16ffc 0x2395 0x22d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)`
as well as a Thread 1: SIGBRT error

The files only include the default content and I have not added anything to them. I have also had this error when declaring the xib file to use for iPad so I let it chose the only xib file that existed. Now with a separate one for iPhone I have to explicitly declare the xib file to use otherwise it uses the iPad one which does not fit on the screen.

Comment: Try searching for the error: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click on the **xib** file to see referencing Outlets. Turned-out some of the control that still referencing and older name and causing this error to happen.

Comment: Ok So I have fixed the issue with the SIGBRT but now it gives me the iPad version in the simulator rather than the Hello World text present in the iPhone xib file. I have declared the file in the Main nib file base name (iPhone) as iPhoneViewController but it shows the iPad xib file but enlarged because the text bar and everything is larger than the screen.

Comment: run it in iPhone simulator,, choose iPhone simulator instead of iPad simulator,

Comment: I am using the iPhone simulator but the interface does not match the one in the iPhone xib file it uses the interface in the iPad xib file.